# Ansible lineinfile duplicates line

Tags: ansible

I have a simple file at /etc/foo.txt. The file contains the following:

```
#bar
```

I have the following ansible playbook task to uncomment the line above:

```
- name: test lineinfile
  lineinfile: backup=yes state=present dest=/etc/foo.txt
              regexp='^#bar'
              line='bar'
```

When I first run ansible-playbook, the line gets uncommented and the /etc/foo.txt now contains the following:

```
bar
```

However, if I run ansible-playbook again, I get the following:

```
bar
bar
```

If I run it yet again, then the /etc/foo.txt file will look like this:

```
bar
bar
bar
```

How to avoid this duplications of lines? I just want to uncomment the '#bar' and be done with it.

Comment: Use [replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html#replace-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression) to "`just uncomment the '#bar' and be done with it`".

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The problem is the task's regex only matches the commented out line, `#bar`. To be idempotent, the lineinfile task needs to match both the commented *and* uncommented state of the line. This way it will uncomment `#bar` but will pass `bar` unchanged.

This task should do what you want:

```yaml
- name: test lineinfile
  lineinfile: 
    backup: yes
    state: present
    dest: /etc/foo.txt
    regexp: '^#?bar'
    line: 'bar'
```

Note the only change was adding a `?` to the regex.

Comment: But that always changes the file.  My understanding was that the line only gets inserted (file modified) when the regexp matched.

Comment: As long as the file comes out the same every time, the task is idempotent. That's all that matters.

Comment: I found out the hard way that if you use `insertafter` in combination with this, you end up with duplicate lines again. `insertafter` breaks this formula.

Answer (score 73):

You need to add **backrefs=yes** if you don't want to change your regular expression.

```
- name: test lineinfile
  lineinfile: backup=yes state=present dest=/etc/foo.txt
              regexp='^#bar' backrefs=yes
              line='bar'
```

This changes the behavior of [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) from:

```
 find
 if found
   replace line found
 else
   add line
```

to:

```
 find
 if found
   replace line found
```

In other words, this makes operation idempotent.

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4531.

The solution is to not replace the commented out line, but to add an additional line, while keeping the original there.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who came here after looking at their file full of duplicate lines: a simple way to remove the duplicates and get back to a "good state" is, to use "state=absent" with the orginal regex.

For Example:

```
- name: clean KexAlgorithms
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/ssh/sshd_config
              regexp="^KexAlgorithms"
              state=absent
```

And then just re-adding them correctly.